# Можно пару советов. как написать на ванильном JS?

Tags: javascript

Можно пару советов. как написать на ванильном JS
чтобы через 5 секунд на сайте, user переходил на другой сайт какой-то например google.

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  this.setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.replace('https://google.com');
    },
    5000
  )
});
```